# Passing a signed number to function macro

Tags: c, macros, negative-number

In the following, can I **always** be sure that x will be *signed* when passed through `testmacro`, since I can't specify the parameter type?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 signed char testval;
 #define testmacro(x) testval = x; printf("%i\n", testval)

 int main() {
    signed char inval;
    inval = -32;
    testmacro(inval);
    inval = 32;
    testmacro(inval);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a function and have the defined macro use the function?

Comment: The idea was that I with using macros could plug in alternative logging in other source files if need be. Thus this would be a fallback if no other logging "interface" was included.

Comment: There is no reason for this fallback not use a function (through a macro if necessary).

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll make the question more general. I'm still curious about the main issue.

Comment: It may be either signed or unsigned, it depends on the compiler.